# Transparent encryption of bash history?

Tags: bash, encryption

I'm not sure if anyone has done such things before.

I want bash history to be fully encrypted, prompt for password when in interactive session.

Is that possible?

Comment: That sounds hard to implement and not useful. Do you want to type your password each time you start a new shell? Each time you do a history search? Why not simply encrypt your home directory (which is bound to contain things that are a lot more confidential than your shell history)?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't possible; Bash has no such feature. More importantly, the idea is deeply flawed.

Whom are you hiding your history from?

Is it an attacker must have access to your home directory and can read your "dot" configuration files and other material. Why don't you just use permissions to keep them out?

Is the attacker an administrator, not kept out by permissions? (Either has root, or unfettered access to system backups that contain your home directory and so on.)  In that case, why specifically worry about your Bash history? You have no privacy on that system. The attacker can spy on the memory in your running processes.

Is your machine locally secured (accessible only by you), but your home directory is mounted on a networked file system? In that case, why don't you use an encrypted file system layer over that networked mount, so that all your files are protected together, not just your Bash history.

As you can see, there is hardly any use case for the whack-a-mole approach to file security (leaving it to each individual application to protect specific files).